# Write multiple dictionaries to csv file with Python standard library

Tags: python

I have this csv file and would like to create a sum of the last four columns and group by the first and third column. Caveat: only the Python standard library is allowed.

```
item1,item2,item3,item4,v1,v2,v3,v4
USA,a,b,c,1,2,3,4
France,d,e,f,5,6,7,8
Japan,g,h,i,9,10,11,12
USA,a,b,y,13,14,15,16
```

Expected output:

```
item1,item3,agg1,agg2,agg3,agg4
USA,b,14,16,18,20
France,e,5,6,7,8
Japan,h,9,10,11,12
```

My code so far:

```
import csv

agg1 = {}
agg2 = {}
agg3 = {}
agg4 = {}


for row in csv.reader(open("my_file.csv")):
    if row[0] != "item1": #skips header
        key = (row[0], row[2])
        agg1[key] = agg1.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[4])
        agg2[key] = agg2.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[5])
        agg3[key] = agg3.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[6])
        agg4[key] = agg4.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[7])
```

Each dictionary contains the output I'm looking for, but how do I write this to a csv file given that my keys are tuples and I want to split them across multiple columns as well as add columns with aggregations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a mapping built (with `key` that also serves as the key to the final sum) that is useful to you. You can use that and it will scale much better than individual dictionaries:

```
import csv 

with open(ur_file) as f_in:
    r=csv.reader(f_in)
    header=next(r)
    result={}
    for row in r:
        key=(row[0], row[2])
        if key in result:
            result[key]=map(sum, zip(result[key], map(float, row[4:])))
        else:
            result[key]=map(float, row[4:])
        
# print block - replace with csv output if desired  
for k,v in result.items():
    print(','.join(map(str, k+tuple(v))))
```

Prints:

```
USA,b,14.0,16.0,18.0,20.0
France,e,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0
Japan,h,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
```

If you want to write to a csv instead, you can replace the `print` block with:

```
with open('out.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    o=csv.writer(f_out)
    o.writerow([header[0],header[2], 'agg1','agg2','agg3','agg4'])
    for k,v in result.items():
        o.writerow(map(str, k+tuple(v)))
```

Which results in the file:

```
$ cat out.csv
item1,item3,agg1,agg2,agg3,agg4
USA,b,14.0,16.0,18.0,20.0
France,e,5.0,6.0,7.0,8.0
Japan,h,9.0,10.0,11.0,12.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to:

- open the file inside a context with the `with` keyword (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/);
- take outside the context the content of the CSV file;
- compute your aggregation operation;
- open a new context with the target file and write at each iteration a line with the desired content

```
    import csv
    
    with open("my_file.csv") as csvfile:
       rows = csv.reader(csvfile)
    
    agg1 = {}
    agg2 = {}
    agg3 = {}
    agg4 = {}
    
    for row in rows:
       if row[0] != "item1": #skips header
          key = (row[0], row[2])
          agg1[key] = agg1.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[4])
          agg2[key] = agg2.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[5])
          agg3[key] = agg3.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[6])
          agg4[key] = agg4.setdefault(key, 0) + float(row[7])
    
    with open("target.csv") as csvfile:
       writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
       writer.writerow(["item1","item3","agg1","agg2","agg3","agg4"])
       for k, v in agg1.items():
          writer.writerow([k[0], k[1], agg1[k], agg2[k], agg3[k], agg4[k]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your code, you can just write your result csv like that:

```
agg_list = [agg1, agg2, agg3, agg4]

header = "item1,item3,agg1,agg2,agg3,agg4"

with open("result.csv", "w") as f:
    f.write(header + '\n')
    for key in agg1:
        f.write(','.join(key))
        for agg in agg_list:
            f.write(',' + str(int(agg[key])))
        f.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also leverage dynamic code generation, using [convtools](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools) library:

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table

# this only reads header here
table = Table.from_csv("my_file.csv", header=True)

# take names of last four columns
columns_to_aggregate = table.columns[4:]

# cast each of these last four columns to float
rows = table.update(
    **{
        col_name: c.col(col_name).as_type(float)
        for col_name in columns_to_aggregate
    }
).into_iter_rows(dict)

# columns to group by are left as is
agg_config = {
    "item1": c.item("item1"),
    "item3": c.item("item3"),
}
for col_name in columns_to_aggregate:
    # defining aggregation for each column
    agg_config[col_name] = c.ReduceFuncs.Sum(c.item(col_name))

# this generates the converter function based on everything above
converter = (
    c.group_by(c.item("item1"), c.item("item3"))
    .aggregate(agg_config)
    .gen_converter()
)
# process rows
processed_rows = converter(rows)

# output to csv
Table.from_rows(processed_rows).into_csv("my_file_out.csv")
```